# IntelliJ gives spurious "not found" errors in Scala 3 project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm starting a Scala 3 project in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.4 (Community Edition).

My problem is that I am getting spurious "Not found errors" as in the image below. Type `Fun` is in the same package (`model`), and Intellij evidently knows the type, as all the information about is correctly displayed right below the error message. The program also compiles without error, even though it is marked as an error and reported in IntelliJ's "Problems" pane.

[image: Not found]

Further info:

The build tool is sbt (but I've had exactly the same problem with Gradle).

The problem disappears when switching to Scala 2, but I would like to avoid that.

I'm also using antlr and stringtemplates in the same project (but I don't know how this could be relevant).

I would be highly grateful for any help.

Comment: Current version of Idea is 2022.2.3. Try to upgrade. Also make sure that Scala plugin is the latest (Scala 3 support is being actively developed, so consider to switch to nightly updates).

Comment: IntelliJ support for Scala 3 and Scala 3 features in Scala 2 is still in development. I am having a lot of false errors even with newest nightly. I guess you can only report issues in their bug tracker.